# NodeJs StrongLoop nested callbacks not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have written a custom endpoint API in LoopBack by StrongLoop, but it doesn't work properly. At first it works fine but on second or third iteration it doesn't work e.g If I post word "API" it works, then if I search "eat" it works also but when I post word "API" again it doesn't work i.e browser goes into loop.
Im using nested callbacks. Here is my code

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
var request = require('request');
var router = app.loopback.Router();
var Verb = app.models.verb;
var Noun = app.models.noun;
var AdditionalTag = app.models.additionalTag;
var responseArray = [];

var verbMatched = false;
var nounMatched = false;

router.get('/api/additionalTagsSuggestions', function(req, res) {
    var request = req.query;
    if (request.q) {
        var query = request.q.split(",")
        if (query.length > 0) {
            responseArray = [];
            var count = 0;
            var querySize = query.length;
            query.forEach(function(word) {
                getTags(word, function(response) {
                    if (response == true) {
                        count++;
                        //console.log("count", count);
                        if (count == querySize) {
                            //console.log(responseArray);
                            if (responseArray.length > 0) {
                                var temp = [];
                                responseArray.forEach(function(elem) {
                                    temp.push.apply(temp, elem.tags);
                                }, this);
                                temp = temp.filter(function(elem, pos) {
                                    return temp.indexOf(elem) == pos;
                                })

                                console.log(temp);
                                responseArray = temp;
                                temp = [];
                                res.send(responseArray);
                            } else {
                                responseArray = [];
                                //console.log(responseArray);
                                res.send(responseArray);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        count++;
                        if (count == querySize) {
                            responseArray = [];
                            res.send(responseArray);
                        }
                    }
                })

            }, this);
        }
    } else {
        responseArray = [];
        res.send(responseArray);
    }
});

function getTags(word, callback) {
    Verb.find(function(err, verbs) {
        if (err) {
            //console.log("error finding verb");
        } else {
            if (verbs.length > 0) {
                verbs[0]["verbs"].forEach(function(verb) {
                    if (verb == word) {
                        verbMatched = true;
                        getNouns(word, function(response) {
                            callback(response);
                        });
                    }
                });
                if (!verbMatched) {

                    verbMatched = false;
                    getNouns(word, function(response) {
                        callback(response);
                    });
                }
            } else {

                verbMatched = false;
                getNouns(word, function(response) {
                    callback(response);
                });
            }

        }
    })
}

function getNouns(word, callback) {
    if (verbMatched) {
        Noun.find({ "fields": { "noun": 1 }, "where": { "verbs": word } }, function(err, arr) {
            if (arr) {
                if (arr.length > 0) {
                    nounMatched = true;
                    getAdditionalTags(arr, function(response) {
                        callback(response);
                    });
                } else {
                    callback(false);
                }
            } else {
                callback(false);
            }
        });
    } else if (!verbMatched) {
        Noun.find({ fields: { noun: true }, where: { noun: word } }, function(err, arr) {
            if (arr) {
                if (arr.length > 0) {
                    nounMatched = true;
                    getAdditionalTags(arr, function(response) {
                        callback(response);
                    });
                } else {
                    nounMatched = false;
                    getAdditionalTags(word, function(response) {
                        callback(response);
                    });
                }
            } else {
                callback(false);
            }
        });
    }
}

function getAdditionalTags(arr, callback) {
    if (nounMatched) {
        var arrSize = arr.length;
        var count = 0;
        arr.forEach(function(obj) {
            AdditionalTag.find({ fields: { tags: true }, where: { noun: obj.noun } }, function(err, tags) {
                if (tags) {
                    if (tags.length > 0) {
                        count++;
                        tags.forEach(function(tag) {
                            responseArray.push(tag);
                        }, this);
                        if (count == arrSize) {
                            console.log("lala");
                            //console.log(responseArray);
                            callback(true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        count++;
                        if (count == arrSize) {
                            console.log("asdfas");
                            callback(false);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    callback(false);
                }

            })
        }, this);
    } else if (!nounMatched) {
        AdditionalTag.find({ fields: { noun: true }, where: { tags: arr } }, function(err, nouns) {
            if (nouns) {
                if (nouns.length > 0) {
                    nounMatched = true;
                    getAdditionalTags(nouns, function(response) {
                        callback(response);
                    });
                } else {
                    callback(false);
                }
            } else {
                callback(false);
            }
        })
    }
}

app.use(router);
```

};

Kindly help me on this issue. Is this a callback hell problem? If so, how can I resolve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "the browser goes into loop"?

Comment: Why do you have those many functions? `getTags`, `getPosts` and `getUser` appear to be doing exactly the same.

Comment: Means the browser keeps on loading but does not give response.

Comment: what kind of error you see on server-side

Comment: @Bergi Actually I have written some more conditional logics in my code depending on which functions are called. This is just a simple structure of my code. My conditions are working fine as per my algorithm.

Comment: @p0k8_ I do not see any error nor any response. The page keeps on loading if I hit api directly.

Comment: that means no response has been send

Comment: @p0k8_ exactly. I tried logging something in my third getUser function to check whether it gets invoked or not but on first try it invokes but on third try I face same problem

Comment: third means getTags, if it's then use a else case and send the response for else

Comment: @ShahrukhShahid Show us that conditional logic, this is likely where the culprit is. The code you posted does not reproduce the behaviour you described.

Comment: @ShahrukhShahid add some relevant code

Comment: @ShahrukhShahid What does the network panel of your devtools say? Do the requests themselves hang, or is just the callback not getting called? If you put a `console.log` in the callback of `getUser`, do you see that happening? What other debugging have you done?

Comment: @Bergi I have updated my code. Please look at that.

Comment: @p0k8_ Updated. Please have a look

Comment: `getTags` does sometimes never call its callback and sometimes multiple times.

Comment: can you please specify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are reimplementing a lot of loopback's functionnality, while doing it with a lot of synchronous operations which are blocking your server. Probably calling multiple times the callback functions. Without passing errors properly to your callbacks.

:)

The good news is, what you're trying to achieve is pretty easy to do with LB.

If I understand your code properly, you are simply trying to call a custom function from a custom URL. This is called a [remote method](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-methods.html).

> In `model/AdditionalTag`

Here is an example code that does what 90% of your code does (like splitting query parameters, validating inputs, etc).

```
module.exports = function(additionalTag){

    additionalTag.suggestion = function(param1, param2, cb) {

      // Put your custom logic here, where you identify additional tags from the parameters and your application data
      // You DON'T need to manually separate the query fields anymore using ','
      // Loopback does that for you, just use param1, param2, etc.

      // Then call back to send the http response 
      // null means no error was found
      // here the remote method returns a string. You can return anything else, like a json object, array, number, etc.
      cb(null, 'Additional tags found.'); 
    }

    // Here you register the function additionalTag.suggestion as a remotely callable one
    additionalTag.remoteMethod('suggestion', {
          accepts: [
            {arg: 'param1', type: 'string'},
            {arg: 'param2', type: 'string'}
          ],
          returns: {arg: 'message', type: 'string'}
    });
};
```

In your best interest, you should study javascript a bit more without going back to loopback. It's a great framework but it requires some good basic knowledge of JS.

Then, try to keep your code simple and readable.
If it isn't then refactor it, make it shorter, split it in clear and simple functions.

And if really you need multiple callbacks, organize them using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library or use [Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises).